# My apache server has stopped running after ssl update on a live site

Tags: ubuntu, centos, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have a standard amazon ami(The one created by amazon), which has apache installed on it. We needed to update the ssl certificate which i did by going through [these steps](http://jafty.com/blog/installing-godaddy-ssl-certificate-on-amazon-ec2/)

I have done this before so i think i didn't do anything wrong. The steps basically included:
1) openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr
2) Updating the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file.
3) Restarting the service httpd

But after restarting httpd i.e sudo service httpd restart. The service stopped fine, but did not start again. Here is the error i am recieving.

```
[ec2-user@******* conf.d]$ service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: [Tue Dec 06 20:38:28 2016] [warn] module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
[Tue Dec 06 20:38:28 2016] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

This is really important, so will really appreciate if someone could me out here. Thanks

**Update:** Ok so i managed to remove the mod_ssl already loaded message. can some one figure this one out?

```
[ec2-user@****** ~]$ sudo service httpd start
Starting httpd: [Tue Dec 06 21:33:52 2016] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are running the restart command as an unprivileged user, as can be seen because the httpd stop fails. You should run the restart command with a suitably privileged account.

---

Update:

> Starting httpd: [Tue Dec 06 21:33:52 2016] [warn] *default* VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
>   (98)Address already in use: **make_sock: could not bind to address** [::]:443

Something is still bound to/listening on port 443. It looks like you have failed to stop the previous invocation of httpd.

Comment: thankyou for your response i have been waiting anxiously. Well i am using the ec2-user account and also using sudo before the commands. I have created ssl certificate before as well with the same account.

Comment: Do you know the location where i can find the logs for httpd

Comment: I know where the default location is yes but I expect you have found your logs as you've had 20 minutes or so to figure it out.

Comment: Yes i did. I ran grep -ir 443 /etc/httpd/conf* which showed that i have been using 2 config files because i renamed my files to conf_bkup.conf. Which i thought was supposed to make a backup file. Anyways now all the errors are gone but i still cant do service httpd restart. Its failing

Answer (score 1):

**I figured out the issue. If anybody came across this issue, because of ssl certificate here are the things you need to check.**

1. First make sure there are not more than 1 configuration file for httpd. (In my case I made a backup file of `etc/httpd/conf/ssl.conf` and called it ***ssl_bkup.conf***. I thought this wont be used as a configuration but it did. I should have used ***ssl.conf_backup***). You can check if there are more than 1 configuration files being used by this command.

   `grep -ir 443 /etc/httpd/conf*`
2. Then check your logs by

   `sudo nano var/log/httpd/error_log`

   `sudo nano var/log/httpd/ssl_log`

   `sudo nano var/log/httpd/nss_log (nss is similar to ssl)`
3. The main issue in my case happened when I was copying the csr files from my computer to the server. The files given by the ssl authority had to be moved to my server, so instead of ftp I was creating new file and copying the content of the csr file into new file created on the server. While doing this I messed up the format in which the files were supposed to be copied.

Because my ftp access was very limited so in order to properly get them on the server I uploaded the files to an online host host and then downloaded to my server via wget.

Comment: Any file ending in *.conf is loaded. Backup files are typically named httpd.conf.bak or similar appending a suffix after the .conf to prevent the file from loading. Glad to hear that you figured out the issue.

Comment: Well i feel stupid now, knowing that out of all the things i was thinking this was something that actually stopped our whole operation. Cheers mate